# Laravel Group By and Sum total value of other column

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table in my database as shown below:

```
id | date       | amount
========================
1  | 2015-01-26 | 1000
2  | 2015-02-26 | 100
3  | 2014-06-26 | 10
```

I want to group the records by year and then find the sum of the amount of each group.

I can find the groups using the following query:

```
Fee::orderBy('date', 'DESC')
  ->get()
  ->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('Y'); // grouping by years
})
```

But I am not able to get the sum of amount of each group.

Comment: You should be calling `->get()`/`->sum('amount')` at the end of the method chaining. Try moving it and let us know if you are getting what you need. Also, are you currently getting some results or an error? Please share the error if you're receiving one.

Comment: @haakym  It groups the resultset  by year.

Comment: I realise that. I'm asking you does it create an error with your original code or does it return a set of data?

Comment: I want to have similar query in laravel.

SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS "Total amount"
 FROM fees 
GROUP BY Year(date)

Comment: I realise that. I'm asking you a question: does the code in your question work - YES OR NO? If NO, what happens: do you get an ERROR or do you get DATA. What does the error or the data look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Afraid I can't figure it out right now with eloquent, this should work for the query builder though. It's working okay for me:

```
DB::table('fees')
    ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(date) as year'), DB::raw('sum(amount) as total'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(date)') )
    ->get();
```

Using the same date you put in the question:

```
id       date                       amount
 1       2015-01-26                  1000
 2       2015-02-26                  100
 3       2014-06-26                  10
```

And it gives the following:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#150 ▼
    +"year": 2014
    +"total": "10"
  }
  1 => {#151 ▼
    +"year": 2015
    +"total": "1100"
  }
]
```

Comment: I apply your solution but it gives an error .
" strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given".
But if give following it returns the zero(0).
Fee::orderBy('date', 'DESC')
 ->get()
 ->groupBy(function($date) {
             return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('Y'); 
       })
        ->sum('amount');